# how to resolve Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareInhouseDebugAndroidTestDependencies'.

Tags: android, api

i am using google api for signing in. while doing that i get this error after adding libraries,

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareInhouseDebugAndroidTestDependencies'.> Dependency Error.
```

how can i resolve it.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

i found my answer.
in my app graddle i was using,

```
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.2'
```

i changed this by,

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

in project graddle i used,

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

happy to get more information.